# SQL Server 2008 - MERGE INTO as a loop: syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am attempting to run an SQL query, which includes a MERGE INTO statement, that loops through each month.

I am getting a couple of syntax errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 35 Incorrect syntax near ','.

It is printing the month/year correctly so I don't think the problem is in the loop, but the merge statement. I looked around but it looks right to me but I am sure I am missing something. I could have sworn I used this code before and it worked.

Here is the code:

```
Declare @StartDate As Datetime set @StartDate = '5/1/2015'; --Update to first month that needs to be added
Declare @StopDate  As Datetime set @StopDate = '12/1/2015'; --Update to last month that needs to be added

Print 'Start Date   ' + Cast(@StartDate as varchar(30));
Print 'Stop Date    ' + Cast(@StopDate as varchar(30));
Print 'Total Months ' + Cast(Datediff(Month, @StartDate, @StopDate) + 1 as varchar(30));
Print ' ';


Declare @Date As Datetime set @Date = @StartDate; 
Declare @SQL_Cmd As Varchar(Max); 

Declare @SQL_Contract_Status As Varchar(Max) set @SQL_Contract_Status =
    '
        MERGE
    INTO        ANNUSER1.RPS_Contract_Person_PT                                        AS TGT
    USING     ( Select
                    P.Datamart_Timestamp
                    ,P.Contract_ID
                    ,P.DOB
                    ,Ltrim(Rtrim(
                       CASE
                         WHEN P.Datamart_Timestamp
                            < CONVERT(DATETIME, ''2007-06-01 00:00:00'', 102)
                          AND Len(P.Name_Last) > 25
                         THEN Substring(P.Name_Last,26,Len(P.Name_Last)-25)
                         ELSE P.Name_First
                       END)) As Name_First
                    ,Ltrim(Rtrim(
                       CASE
                         WHEN P.Datamart_Timestamp
                            < CONVERT(DATETIME, ''2007-06-01 00:00:00'', 102)
                          AND Len(P.Name_Last) > 25
                         THEN LTrim(Left(P.Name_Last,25))
                         ELSE P.Name_Last
                       END)) As Name_Last
                    ,P.Sex
                    ,P.TIN
                    ,P.TIN_Type
                    ,D.Group_Plan_ID
                From   AT_RPS_2015_05_Contract_Person AS P
                       INNER JOIN AT_RPS_2015_05_Contract_Data AS D
                        ON P.Contract_ID = D.Contract_ID
                WHERE  (P.[Role] IN (''PT''))
              ) AS SRC
    ON          (   TGT.Contract_ID = SRC.Contract_ID )
            AND (   TGT.DOB = Cast(SRC.DOB as Date)
                 OR (    TGT.DOB IS NULL
                     AND SRC.DOB IS NULL ) )
            AND (   TGT.Name_First = SRC.Name_First
                 OR (    TGT.Name_First IS NULL
                     AND SRC.Name_First IS NULL ) )
            AND (   TGT.Name_Last = SRC.Name_Last
                 OR (    TGT.Name_Last IS NULL
                     AND SRC.Name_Last IS NULL ) )
            AND (   TGT.Sex = SRC.Sex
                 OR (    TGT.Sex IS NULL
                     AND SRC.Sex IS NULL ) )
            AND (   TGT.TIN = SRC.TIN
                 OR (    TGT.TIN IS NULL
                     AND SRC.TIN IS NULL ) )
            AND (   TGT.TIN_Type = SRC.TIN_Type
                 OR (    TGT.TIN_Type IS NULL
                     AND SRC.TIN_Type IS NULL ) )
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN
    INSERT
           (
                Contract_ID
                ,Sequence_Number
                ,DOB
                ,Name_First
                ,Name_Last
                ,Sex
                ,TIN
                ,TIN_Type
                ,Datamart_Timestamp
                ,Group_Plan_ID
           )
           VALUES
           (
                SRC.Contract_ID
                ,Coalesce(
                    (SELECT Max(Sequence_Number)
                     FROM ANNUSER1.RPS_Contract_Person_PT AS TGT
                     WHERE TGT.Contract_ID = SRC.Contract_ID)
                    ,0) + 1 
                ,Cast(SRC.DOB as Datetime)
                ,SRC.Name_First
                ,SRC.Name_Last
                ,SRC.Sex
                ,SRC.TIN
                ,SRC.TIN_Type
                ,Cast(SRC.Datamart_Timestamp As Datetime)
                ,SRC.Group_Plan_ID
           );                       ';

While @Date <= @StopDate
  Begin
      Set @SQL_Cmd = Replace(Replace(@SQL_Contract_Status, 'YYYY', Year(@Date)), 'MM', Right('0' + Cast(Month(@Date) As Varchar(2)), 2));
      Exec (@SQL_Cmd);
      Print Cast(Year(@Date) as varchar(30)) + '_' + Right('0' + Cast(Month(@Date) as varchar(30)),2) + ' ' + Cast(@@RowCount as varchar(30));
      Set @Date = Dateadd(Month, 1, @date);
  End;

GO
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `PRINT @SQL_Cmd` instead of showing us the code used to generate it?

Comment: I edited the post to show SQL_cmd for the first iteration

Comment: Are you sure? This seems wrong (needs more single quotes): `WHERE  (P.[Role] IN ('PT'))`

Comment: not sure what happened but I think having a quote in the code editor did something that removed one of the quotes... I changed it to what it actually is (with two quotes).

Also fixed it for the two CONVERT lines

Comment: I recommend `sp_executesql` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) instead of EXEC (@SQL_Cmd), as `sp_executesql` will let you pass parameters. This gets you out of the `REPLACE` operation and removes some uncertainty. It also lets you prove your dynamic SQL outside the loop. This assumes that the excerpt is a simplified use case and you really need the dynamic SQL.